# Spring injections do not work in custom hibernate validator while testing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, testng, hibernate-validator

**Test configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@Import( value = GlobalCoreContext.class)
public class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Validator createValidatorFactory() {
        return Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    }

}
```

**ValidatorClass**

```
public final class LoginAttemptsExceededValidatorLoginId implements ConstraintValidator<LoginAttemptsExceeded, String> {

    @Resource
    private LoginDao loginDao;

    private LoginAttemptsExceeded loginAttemptsExceeded;

    @Override
    public void initialize(final LoginAttemptsExceeded loginAttemptsExceeded) {
        this.loginAttemptsExceeded = loginAttemptsExceeded;
    }

    /**
     * Validation fails if the login attempts have exceeded the preset number.
     * @param loginId
     * @param constraintValidatorContext
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String loginId, final ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if(StringUtility.IsEmpty(loginId)) return false;

        return !loginDao.findByLogin(loginId).isLoginAttemptsExceeded();
    }
}
```

**Unit Test class**

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class )
public class LoginAttemptsExceededValidatorLoginIdTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;
    private PasswordChange passwordChange;
    private LoginEntity loginEntity;
    private static final String TEST_PASSWORD = "abcDEFG10";
    private static final String TEST_LOGIN = "passwordChangeValidatorTestLogin";


    @Resource
    private LoginDao loginDao;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        passwordChange = new PasswordChange(TEST_LOGIN, TEST_PASSWORD, "newPassword");

        /**
         * setup a Login record
         */
        loginEntity = DataBuilder.createLogin();
        loginEntity.setLogin(TEST_LOGIN);
        loginEntity.setPasswordHash(encryptToBytes(TEST_PASSWORD));
        loginEntity.setLoginAttempts(0);
        loginDao.saveAndFlush(loginEntity);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Remove the login record.
        loginDao.delete(loginEntity);
        loginDao.flush();
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValid() throws Exception {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<PasswordChange>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(passwordChange);
        assertEquals(constraintViolations.size(), 0, "When a valid username, password are supplied, the number of errors should be zero.");

    }
}
```

**GlobalCoreContext.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.mrll.global.core.entities", "com.mrll.global.core.daos"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mrll.global.core.password", "com.mrll.global.core.util", "com.mrll.global.core.constraints" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({DataSourceContext.class, LiquibaseContext.class})
public class GlobalCoreContext {

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalCoreContext.class);

    private static final String DATASOURCE_SCHEMA = "datasource.schema";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_GEN_DDL = "hibernate.genddl";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_CONN_CHARSET = "hibernate.connection.charSet";
    private static final String ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private org.springframework.core.env.Environment environment;

    @Resource
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManger() {
        try {
            return entityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new PersistenceException("unable to create entity manager", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(Boolean.valueOf(environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL)));
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.valueOf(environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_GEN_DDL)));
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    /**
     * add JPA properties, optionally adding default schema if profile's datasource is Oracle instance.
     *
     * @return Properties to add
     */
    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(HIBERNATE_CONN_CHARSET, environment.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_CONN_CHARSET));
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", true);

        // use this one for hibernate 4.x +
//      properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");

        // use this one for hibernate 3.2.x +
//      properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory");
//      properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", true);
//      properties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", true);

        if (!"H2".equalsIgnoreCase(environment.getRequiredProperty(DataSourceContext.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE))) {
            properties.put("hibernate.default_schema", environment.getRequiredProperty(DATASOURCE_SCHEMA));
        }
        LOG.debug(String.format("properties=%s", properties));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        transactionManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }


    @Bean
    public static Constants getConstants() {
        return Constants.getInstance();
    }
}
```

For some reason, the `loginDao` in **isValid** method inside the `LoginAttemptsExceededValidatorLoginId` is null. ***It works well at runtime.***

But during unit test the `LoginDao` is not injected into the Validator even though the `javax.validation.Validator` is being injected into the UnitTest.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: could you simplify the code a bit that way the bug still occurs but we don't have to read a useless code. There are also classes that may effect the code but we do not see them: GlobalCoreContext, AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests. Thx :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marek. `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` is a SpringTest class. I have added `GlobalCoreContext.java`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that your problem lies here:

```
@Bean
public Validator createValidatorFactory() {
    return Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
}
```

This builds the default Validator, including the default *ConstraintValidatorFactory* which does not inject Spring beans. If you check the documentation you will find

> By default, the LocalValidatorFactoryBean configures a
>   SpringConstraintValidatorFactory that uses Spring to create
>   ConstraintValidator instances. This allows your custom
>   ConstraintValidators to benefit from dependency injection like any
>   other Spring bean.

(see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html)

You have to make sure that your Validator uses the same constraint validator factory. Or why do you not inject LocalValidatorFactoryBean directly into the test? If I understand correctly GlobalCoreContext is where you programmatically configure your beans. Why not add there the LocalValidatorFactoryBean. However, I am not a Spring expert.

Comment: Thankyou adding `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` dirently into a unittest worked great.

Comment: @ShaggyInjun Can you put your sample working code with Hardy's suggestion to help others?